# Как сделать счетчик с увеличениям на 1?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать счетчик с увеличениям на 1 ?

Comment: Увеличением чего? Увеличением по какому событию? Покажите хоть какой нибудь код. Ничего не понятно

Comment: Инкримент обычный чтоли ?

Comment: Скорее всего да, но что-то уж совсем слабенький вопрос ...

Comment: @МаксимКутовой, скорее всего нет. Пример на замыкание для получения счётчика.

Comment: @Qwertiy нам дали куцый вопрос а мы угадываем)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
var i = 2;
i++;      // более короткая запись для i = i + 1.
alert(i); // 3
```

[Первая попавшаяся ссылка в Google](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 1, b = 1, c, d;

c = ++a; alert(c); // 2
d = b++; alert(d); // 1

c = (2+ ++a); alert(c); // 5
d = (2+ b++); alert(d); // 4

alert(a); // 3
alert(b); // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function createCounter(n) {
  n = n || 0;

  return function () {
    return n++;
  };
}

var c1 = createCounter(), c2 = createCounter(), c3 = createCounter(4);

[c3(), c2(), c2(), c1(), c3(), c2()] == "4,0,1,0,5,2";
```

Comment: `n = n == null ? 0 : n;` - а разве так принято? я чаще встречал немного другое: `n = n || 0`. Даже если вместо 0 что-то другое требуется, то может лучше не с null сравнивать, а typeof проверять?

Comment: @BOPOH, согласен, перемудрил. `n = n || 0` тут подходит. `typeof` - это для потенциально необъявленных глобальных переменных. Да и вообще, проверять можно всё что захочется :)